# Getting last page visited

Tags: html, redirect

I have a web site with some static web pages (webSiteA), which has a link to another web application (webAppB).

webAppB must know if the client was redirected from webSiteA. What are my options here?

One option I am thinking about is to create the link with a query string on webSiteA, and webAppB can check for that.

webSiteA is just a static html web site created using some web designer, and will be in http.

I guess the webAppB can also check for the last URL and check the IP for webSiteA, or by using referrer.

Are there any other options that may be considered a better way to do this? How safe is either of the methods above? How easy is it to spoof these?

Comment: Reading the referrer from the HTTP request is the industry standard and the sane way to go.

Comment: But don't assume everybody sends referrer header. Some people like me want privacy, but some websites don't work without that header.

Comment: Referrer is trivial to spoof.

Comment: @Juhana - Please elaborate how is it trivial? In my case it is important to know if user came from webSiteA.

Comment: The user's web browser sends referrer information. [The user/browser can send anything they want](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing). If you use this as a security measure, checking the referrer is not going to work.

Comment: @Juhana: Thanks. This won't be used as a security measure. However, any user can come to webSiteA (no login required) and click on the link for webAppB. webAppB must know if user came from webSiteA or not. How can one do that? What is the best option? can we pass in security token, how?

Answer (score 0):

The basic option is to use the referer.
You say website A is static and you don't need to enforce strong security. In this case the referer is also the only option.

If you need a proof that the user visited site A, you can do something like this :
Put a link like

```
/redirect.php?url=http://site-b/...
```

In this file you add a parameter to the URL that uniquely identifies the client, as for example :

```
http://site-b/...?t=identifier
```

where identifier can be something like

```
$identifier = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $secret_string);
```

On website B you check if the identifier corresponds to the client's footprint. You have a proof that cannot be falsified.